# Java - Reading multiple lines in jtextarea; converting to char array

Tags: java, arrays, char, jtextarea

I am taking an input from a jtextarea and need to be able to read multiple lines from the input and output the calculation. I can read the first line, but none after that (it crashes). Here is the code I have right now

```
        String exp = inputTextArea.getText();
        String[] lines = exp.split("\\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
        {
        InterpObj.p = exp.toCharArray();
        InterpObj.counter = 0;

        double nr = InterpObj.E();
        String str=Double.toString(nr);

        outputTextArea.append(" " +str); 
        }
```

Here are the error messages

```
{Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For     input string: "6 12"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at Interpreter.A(Interpreter.java:43)
at Interpreter.E(Interpreter.java:24)
at Interp_1a$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(Interp_1a.java:91)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: At some point in your interpreter class, you are trying to turn `"6 12"` into a single `double`. It doesn't work like that. Either split the String by space, or only input a single number on each line. As a side note, I wonder if the line `InterpObj.p = exp.toCharArray();` should actually be `InterpObj.p = lines[i].toCharArray();`

Comment: The second part did, dumb mistake. Thank you!! @jonhopkins

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your `Interpreter.E()` method...

> at Interpreter.E(Interpreter.java:24)

Answer (score 0):

Need to change `InterpObj.p = exp.toCharArray();` to `InterpObj.lines[i] = exp.toCharArray();` Thanks to @jonhopkins